# $E[min\{ |X-Y|,1\}]$ convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I do not know if my exercise is well written or is correct.

Let $X$ and $Y$ r.v., let
$$d(X,Y) := E[min\{ |X-Y|,1\}].$$
Prove that $X_n \to X$ in probability if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(X_n,X) = 0$.

($\Rightarrow$) For all $\epsilon>0$
$$P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon] \to 0.$$
i.e. for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $n$ such that
$$P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon] \leq \epsilon.$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
    d(X_n,X) &= E[min\{ |X_n-X|,1\}]\\
    &= E[min\{ |X_n-X|,1\}1_{[|X_n-X|>\epsilon}]]+E[min\{ |X_n-X|,1\}1_{[|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon}]]\\
    &\leq E[min\{ |X_n-X|,1\}1_{[|X_n-X|>\epsilon}]] + E[ |X_n-X| 1_{[|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon}]] \\
    &\leq E[min\{ |X_n-X|,1\}1_{[|X_n-X|>\epsilon}]] + \epsilon E[ 1_{[|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon}]] \\
    &= E[min\{ |X_n-X|,1\}1_{[|X_n-X|>\epsilon}]] + \epsilon P[|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon] \\
    &\leq E[1 \cdot 1_{[|X_n-X|>\epsilon}]] + \epsilon \\
    &\leq P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon] + \epsilon \\
    &\leq \epsilon + \epsilon \\
    &= 2\epsilon
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(X_n,X) = 0.$$

For the other part I do not know how to proceed. I think is a similar argument like the one I used before.

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with the same equalities, but instead of upper bounding $d$, drop the last term to get $d \ge \mathbb{E}[ \min\{ |X_n - X|, 1\} \mathbf{1}\{|X_n - X| > \epsilon\}].$ Now under this event, you can lower bound $\min\{|X_n - X|,1\}$ and proceed.

Comment: for the other part you can do it with a proof by contradiction, that is, assume that $d(X_n,X)\to 0$ but that $X_n$ doesn't converge in probability to $X$

Comment: For the other part, if $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, then $\mathbb P(|X_n-X| > \varepsilon) = \mathbb P( \min\{|X_n-X|,1\} > \varepsilon) \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \mathbb E\min\{|X_n-X|,1\}$

Comment: I did the exercise with your advices. Thanks!!